# POST request with Android Annotation REST Service

Tags: android, spring, rest, android-annotations

I am using [Android Annotation](http://androidannotations.org/) in my project and trying to send `POST` request through following code, however there is something wrong in following code as I am not getting response as expected:

```
@Rest(rootUrl = "http://xyz.com", converters = {GsonHttpMessageConverter.class})
public interface A {

    @Post("/authenticate/email/")
    public Object attemptLogin(Map data);
}
```

Where `data` is `(key, value)` pair. Is there anything I am missing perhaps Do I have to set `request-header` or `data` should not be JSON?

Comment: You really need to provide more information. What response are you expecting? Does the data ever get to the server? What does it look like? etc, etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found the solution from [Rest client using Android-Annotations](http://www.sapandiwakar.in/technical/rest-client-using-android-annotations/).

> Like the GET requests, it is extremely simple to send POST requests using Android-Annotations. One difference is that you need to define the parameters that you are going to send as a custom class (e.g. Event class in the example below) or if you want to control this dynamically, then a Map (e.g. a MultiValueMap). The url for the request can still be constructed in a similar fashion using the variables enclosed inside {...} and the response can be handled similarly as in GET requests.

```
@Post("/events")
void addEvent(Event event);

@Post("/events/{id}")
void addEventById(Event event, long id);

@Post("/authenticate/event/")
Object authenticateEventData(MultiValueMap data);
```

Comment: I only got this fully working right when I used a LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String> object as in the docs (https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/wiki/Rest%20API#post), but thanks for the start.